# react typescript key property not show in the render page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, html-lists

I am using typescript react and got the error message as

> react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

However I do have key in the li tag as :

```
const MyMenuItem:React.FC<MenuItem> =({title, link, cls}) => {
  return (
    <li className="list-group-item" key={title}>
        <Link to={link} className={cls}>
          {title}
        </Link>
    </li>
  )
}
```

I checked the rendered element. in the li section, the key disappeared. Not sure how it happen. Why key disappeared.

Comment: Data in `title` should be unique. You are getting error because `title` is having duplicated data.

Answer (score 0):

You might have the index to be the key. So that it has the only key

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Key should be unique, so maybe title is not unique. Also key should not be put inside the child component instead should be on the component you are rendering in a list.

E.g.

```
   <>
    {items.map((item) => <MyMenuItem key={item.id} />)}
   </>
```

Or if you don't have a usable unique id you can also use index

```
   <>
    {items.map((item, idx) => <MyMenuItem key={idx} />)}
   </>
```

Comment: The titles are unique, as the menu only has a few menu items. I've also have a similar problem in another page, which use ranking as the key, definitely they are unique ...